# Generic method upper bound isn't checked

Tags: java, generics

I've created a generic method with two type paremeter as follow inside a non-generic class:

```
static <T, V extends T> boolean testMethod(T t, V[] v) {
    return true;
}
```

The second type parameter defined as `V extends T`.

Now consider calling of this method by following arguments:

```
testMethod("text", new Integer[]{1, 2});
```

When I try to call this method with the above parameters **I expected to got an error** of type mismatch, because type parameter `T` substituted by `String` and `V` substituted by `Integer` and as you see `V` is bounded by `T` which means **it must be of type String or its derived classes but Integer is non of them**. But the code segment compile and run successfully without any problem.

Can somebody explain what is wrong about my impression of this concept?

Comment: Note that `V` is substituted by `Integer[]`, not `Integer`.

Comment: I thought `V[]` is substituted by `Integer[]` and `V` is substituted by `Integer`? Am I right? @Code-Apprentice

Comment: @MehdiRahimi oh, you are probably right...at least `V` is probably not an array type. But it might be `Object` instead of `Integer`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this method call, the values of the `T` and `V` type parameters are not provided explicitly, so the compiler infers them. It will always try to infer valid substitutions before returning an error, even if the results are not always intuitive. In this example, the value `“text”` is a `String`, yes, but it is also an `Object`. Since the inference `T = String, V = Integer` is invalid because `Integer` is not a subtype of `String`, the compiler uses `T = Object, V = Integer`, which is valid.